# How to create Power View report tiled by multiple KPIs?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, powerview, kpi

I am trying to create a Power View report tiled by KPIs, is this possible?

An example of my raw data:

```
Company ID    Employee ID    Measure    numerator    denominator
1             01             1          2            5
2             04             1          3            6
3             02             1          0            5
4             03             1          1            2
1             01             2          4            4
2             04             2          2            3
2             06             2          0            6
4             01             2          1            4
```

I have created a calculated column in Power Pivot using the following DAX function:

```
RATE:=[numerator]/[denominator]
```

From this, I want to create KPIs for each measure (each measure has different targets), and use these KPIs as tiles in a Power View report filtered by Company ID and/or Employee ID.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot tile by KPI. You KPI has to be a measure and you cannot tile by a measure. You can tile by a calculated column or by any original field in your dataset. So you can drop RATE into a TILE BY box.

To use the Measure column or a KPI type icon as the Tile field the best approach might be to use an image for your measure column. See more on including images in Power View here: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Images-in-Power-View-84e91b90-b1da-4913-83d6-beada5591fce?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA

Comment: I wanted to tile by measure or KPI because I have 33 measures, and wanted to limit the amount of horizontal display. I have improvised using a SUMX(FILTER()) function which allows me to tile by measure and displays the measure-related values when the corresponding tile is selected, but blank columns for the other measures still appear in the table when a non-corresponding tile is selected. Is there any work around to solve this; so only the columns for the related values appear when a tile is selected?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something very wrong. PowerPivot and power view are all about aggregation. I can't figure out how you are running out of space. And it's not helping that you have a column called measure either. Are you looking to display RATE by Company and Employee under different headings of the measure column?

Comment: Yes I want to display RATE by Company and Employee by Measure with a status indicator.